# Blame movie ending - why doesn't Killy go with Cibo and the others?

Tags: blame

From what I understood at the end of the Blame anime movie, Cibo almost succeeded. If it hadn't been for the Safeguard attacking the synthetic terminal, she would have succeeded.

So given this, wouldn't it have been best for Killy to stick with Cibo and for them to try again with another synthetic terminal.

But Killy leaves them and says he's looking for a human with the net terminal gene... I don't get it. Why does he do this? The whole ending felt very strange. They just almost saved the world, but Killy is now acting that it was all a lost cause.